# How to filter SQL results using multiple WHERE clauses?

Tags: mysql

I have database "aim" table namely trandate, account,account name,  amount

```
Date    Account     Account Name           Amount
2015-01-05   000010     Cash on Hand            1,000.00  
2015-01-05   000011     Check Item              5,000.00
2015-01-05   000012     Taxes                     500.00
2015-01-05   000013     Bank Deposit           10,000.00
2015-01-05   000014     Loan Discount             100.00
2015-01-05   000015     Travel                     20.00
2015-01-06   000010     Cash on Hand            3,500.00  
2015-01-06   000011     Check Item              1,000.00
2015-01-06   000012     Taxes                     100.00
2015-01-06   000013     Bank Deposit           20,000.00
2015-01-06   000014     Loan Discount             200.00
2015-01-06   000015     Travel                     50.00
```

Now my SQL is

```
Select * from aim where date = 20150106 or Account between 
000012 and 000014
```

I want an answer like this

```
2015-01-06   000010     Cash on Hand            3,500.00
2015-01-06   000012     Taxes                     100.00
2015-01-06   000013     Bank Deposit           20,000.00
2015-01-06   000014     Loan Discount             200.00
```

My query is filtered with date and account. I want to include "Cash on hand" in the query but it is not belong to BETWEEN clause.

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: try this Select * from aim where date = 20150106 or (Account between 
000012 and 000014 or Account=000010)

Comment: @HadiHassan - I believe 20150106 or should be 20150106 and

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a condition to your where statement:

```
Select * from aim where date = 20150106 and( Account between 
000012 and 000014 or Account = `000010` )
```